# How to pass a constant to my DynamicArray class add method

Tags: c++

My DynamicArray is pretty much an ArrayList. I want to allow users to have a contiguous block of memory where elements are one after another, and there is additional space if needed. The only problem I came across was storing ints/floats/bools etc... I decided to make my _array a T** so that I could store them.

However, I'm having a bit of trouble passing constants to my DynamicArray's add method. I need to store values in a variable before I pass them otherwise I get this error:

```
    g++ main.cpp -Wall -Werror -std=c++0x

    main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:14:21: error: no matching function for call to ‘triforce::DynamicArray<std::basic_string<char> >::add(const char [5])’
main.cpp:14:21: note: candidates are:
DynamicArray.h:150:10: note: bool triforce::DynamicArray<T>::add(T&) [with T = std::basic_string<char>]
DynamicArray.h:150:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const char [5]’ to ‘std::basic_string<char>&’
DynamicArray.h:176:10: note: void triforce::DynamicArray<T>::add(uint, T&) [with T = std::basic_string<char>, uint = unsigned int]
DynamicArray.h:176:10: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
```

My DynamicArray has a T** variable named _array.

```
/**
144      * @brief Adds an element to the end of the array. The array will double in size,
145      * if needed.
146      * @param element The element to be added to the array.
147      * @returns Returns if the element was added successfully.
148      */
149     template<class T>
150     bool DynamicArray<T>::add(T& element)
151     {
152         if(_array == NULL)
153         {
154             errorMsg("Cannot add to null array");
155             return false;
156         }
157 
158         if(_size == _capacity)
159         {
160             increaseCapacity(_capacity * 2);
161         }
162 
163         _array[_size] = &element;
164         _size++;
165 
166         return true;
167     }
```

This works:

```
13     string val1 = "val1";
 14     array.add(val1);
```

This doesn't work

```
13     string val1 = "val1";
 14     array.add("val1");
```

How do I make it so this function can accept constants like just passing 1 or the string "hello" without putting it in a variable first? I tried putting const in the parameter, but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: And you are not using std::vector because...?

Comment: Everything I use in my class must be built from scratch.

Comment: Note that in C++, unlike Java, a double-quoted string is not an instance of the string class; it's merely an array of char. Your problem arises because you're assuming the two are interchangeable, but they're not. You need to slow down and read a book or two. C++ and Java aren't all that alike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example below:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
void foo( T& arg )
{
  static_assert( std::is_same<T&, const char(&)[6]>::value, "Must be same" );
}

int main()
{
  foo( "Hallo world" );
  return 0;
}
```

the type is deduced as const char[6].  then becomes a reference to an array, and therefore has type:

const char (&array)[6]

The name of an array (without qualification by operator []) decays to type char*, or in this case const char*:

```
_array[_size] = &element;
```

therefore taking its address, the type of the rhs here above becomes const char**, and it is not possible to assign a variable of type const char** to a variable of type char& (which is returned by _array[size].

You could remedy this as follows:

```
template<class T>
void DynamicArray<T>::add( const T& element )
{
  if(_size == _capacity)
  {
    increaseCapacity(_capacity * 2);
  }
  _array[_size] = element;
  _size++;
}

//------ Added code --------
template<class T>
  template <int N> 
void DynamicArray<T>::add( const T (&array) [N] )
{
  for( std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i )
  {
    //Calls your add per element...
    add( array[i] );
  }
}
```

Note that you will not be able to use std::string in the code here above. For this another overload would be required. Also note that my functions have no return type (as yours did). The return type had no purpose in your code, as any errors (as result of e.g dynamic allocation) would have thrown.

Lastly, as mentioned elsewhere, the code here above are merely written to understand concepts. In reality one would use a std::vector, which is of course already a dynamic array.

Comment: I tried attempting your solution with int, but I got an error on the line with:
_array[_size] = element;

So if _array is a T** shouldn't that be okay? element is a copy of the address of 1.

My call: array.add(1);

Comment: This all depends with what type you've instantiated your class. If the type of DynamicArray is char, and you've used T&, and not T, it means that the compiler needs to convert the literal, and a temporary cannot bind to a l-value reference:

Comment: However, if you use type (const T& ) as argument, int should be [is] convertable to this, as int can convert to char.

Comment: The compiler error would typically be: prog.cpp:8:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘char&’

Comment: Sorry for not specifying. I am using DynamicArray<int>. The error I get is error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’. I'm sure this is because my _array is a T**. So _array[_size] is expecting an int*. I'm not really sure how to handle that. If I take the address then I'm going to get the invalid conversion from 'const int*' to 'int*'.

Comment: Array should be of type int*, therefore:

Comment: T *array_; array_ = new T[someSize];

Comment: Okay if I do that then there is no way to represent NULL. I wouldn't be able to tell the difference between what the user set as 0, and what is actually NULL. This is why I refrained from doing what you just suggested.

Comment: Then your array does not represent a normal array. The value zero is null, for all practical purposes (eg in a char array). Look at the implementation of vector...

Answer (score 0):

The third note line spells out the problem:

> `DynamicArray.h:150:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const char [5]’ to ‘std::basic_string<char>&’`

So, your `DynamicArray<string>` is trying to convert a string literal into a `std::string &`, and there is no way to do that.

You can do as you tried, create the `string` before hand, or you can modify your `add()` method to not take a reference.

```
 template<class T>
 bool DynamicArray<T>::add(T element)
 {
     //...
```

This way, a copy is made for you on the stack, initialized by the string literal that will be passed to its constructor.

Comment: The only problem with passing by value is storing these to my _array. If I store the reference of element won't element just pop off the stack? When I do pass by value I always get the max int value when I output all the elements in my DynamicArray. Also how does Vector allow you to pass a constant with this signature: const value_type& val

Comment: You don't show enough code in your question for me to put any of your questions into context.

Comment: Sure just let me know what you need to see. Do you want the whole class? I wasn't sure if I was allowed to post 500 lines of code.